# Constrain \@ifnextchar to the same line

Tags: expl3, optional-arguments, line

I need an environment that takes an optional argument between square brackets, but only when provided on the same line as the `\begin{...}` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def \MyTest {
\@ifnextchar[{TRUE} {FALSE}
}
\makeatother
SUCCESS: \MyTest
A\\
Next should be FALSE:
\MyTest
[B\\
\newenvironment{TEST}{\MyTest}{}
SUCCESS: \begin{TEST}\end{TEST}
SUCCESS: \begin{TEST}[\end{TEST}\\
Next should be FALSE:
\begin{TEST}
[\end{TEST}
\end{document}
```

This behavior is the same for the `Verbatim` environment of the `fancyvrb` package,
but the source code is rather complicated to extract the relevant part.

I have tried to use `\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF` or `\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF` to recognize an EOL, to no avail.

How can I implement such a `\@ifnextchar` preferably with `expl3` but any solution is welcome.

Comment: you can use the version from `amsmath` that does his.

Comment: it's more reliable to not allow white space of any sort as restricting to newline doesn't work in arguments of other commands as newline will already be tokenised as space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but can you? In the example the optional argument comes after \MyTest and on its own that already parses away blanks (and newlines) until it hits the [. The whole amsmath (or fancyvrb) constructs only work because they are call as part of an environment. So yes, it can be done, but not when used on top-level as in the first part of the MWE.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach ah Jérôme could call his `\MyTest` function `\\ ` then the `ams` version would work....